# How can I delete objects from array?

Tags: modeling, texturing, modifiers, edit-mode, vertices

[image]

Hello, so I made this array that didn't fit on my whole balcony curve of my numbs path. I decided to copy paste and place them next to each other. problem is now, as you can see, that the array turned too long by 4 pillars. How can I delete those 4 pillars without deleting the whole array?

Best

Comment: there's probably a better way, but the only way I know is to apply the array modifier and then delete the resulting extra objects.  The multiple meshes will still be one object so you can do it in edit mode. Another way is to count the objects now, switch the array to count and set to the count to 4 fewer than you currently have.

Comment: I have no Idea how, but I switched to fixed count and It stayed on the curve even tho it wasn't set on fixed cure.. It worked out but I dunno why

Comment: It stays on the curve because of the curve modifier.  That one tells the array to follow the curve.

Comment: You can go to edit mode and delete the vertices of those last four columns.

Comment: FYI the length is not calculated correctly because you arrayed object's scale is not 1,1,1. Apply scale with CTRL A > Scale and it will correctly array along the curve